# Using reflection to convert a non-generic dictionary to a generic one, without the generic parameters

Tags: c#, xml, dictionary, generics, reflection

I'm working on custom XML serialization for [this PropertyList DTD](https://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd), and so far I've fully covered all the types except "dict". Some of the dicts are essentially objects like this:

```cs
<key>1</key>
<dict>
    <key>Track ID</key><integer>1</integer>
    <key>Name</key><string>Baby</string>
    <key>Artist</key><string>Justin Bieber</string>
    [...]
</dict>
```

Which I've already handled.

`property.SetValue(obj, xmlReader.ReadElementContentAs(propertyType, null));`

For arrays, I was able to use the untyped `Array` class (using the `ArrayList` class to build it), which lets one work with type variables instead of generics, and then conveniently can go straight into the `SetValue` method and automatically converted to the `int[]` or whatever other generic is in the object.

```
ArrayList array = new ArrayList();
do
{
    array.Add(GetDictValue(arrayReader, elementType));
}
while (arrayReader.ReadToFollowing(elementTypeName));
property.SetValue(obj, array.ToArray(elementType));
```

But I cannot find any such way to do this for dictionaries. `Hashtable` cannot convert to a generic `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` without the generic parameters.

Comment: If starting with `IDictionary<string, object>`, does this "issue" persist? All the keys appear to be strings, and values can be mixed..

Answer (score 1):

I would create a 2nd xmlreader to read the child :

```
            XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(@"c:\temp\test.xml");
            reader.ReadToFollowing("ENVELOPE");
            StringReader sReader = new StringReader(reader.ReadInnerXml());
            XmlReader childReader = XmlReader.Create(sReader);
            childReader.MoveToContent();
            reader.MoveToContent();
```